# My AWS Codebuild Docker Sample not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I have created a Docker Sample for CodeBuild using following official documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html#sample-docker-docker-hub

I have followed the exact same steps but when I start the build in Codebuild it showing error in my build-phase: Attaching the error which is shown in logs:
[CodeBuild logs showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sin3F.png)

I have used the environment variables properly according to the documentation:
[Env Variables screenshot(have erased account ID from this image for security)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKON4.png)

I have also created the new ECR repo name my_ecr_repo(currently the repo is empty as it is newly created)

Also below is my buildspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image... 
      - echo $IMAGE_REPO_NAME
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Can anyone help me why is the error being shown?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Seems like "IMAGE_REPO_NAME" is empty. Can you `echo` it in codebuild to see what it contains?

Comment: I added - echo $IMAGE_REPO_NAME  in build file after - echo Building the Docker image...  statement. But showing empty in output. Is this correct command for echoing env_variiable? Also but I have created the repo with same name in ecr in same region and has passed it in environment variable too as you can see that in screenshot I have uploaded above

Comment: Yes, its correct and as I suspected, `$IMAGE_REPO_NAME` is empty. Something is overwriting it. Does your `buildspec.yml` contain [env](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax) section? Also, can you post your build spec file.

Comment: Hi, I have added buildspec.yml in the question

Comment: The file looks fine. Have to find out why `IMAGE_REPO_NAME` is empty. Double check env setting in concole. maybe you are build wrong build project?

Comment: I tried to find it but didn't found much. I also verified I am building the right project

Comment: I think the last thing to do is to create new project and start again. I don't now at present what's happening. Sorry.